# How many FaceID and TouchID attempts are possible with iOS/Apple Biometric Framework and Is it possible to change the attempt/count of retry?

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, touch-id, face-id

I would like to know how many **attempts** does 'Apple Biometric Framework' [FaceID and TouchID] provide on login failure using Biometric?

Can we change or customize the attempt count/ retry count?
If yes, how ? If no, why?

I tried searching online but found few articles that tell more about how to implement the functionality but doesn't say much about attempt/count to retry login, via FaceID and Touch ID. Neither it say anything about customizing the retry count.

Thanks.

Comment: Authentication is controlled via the system and you cannot configure it per app.

Answer (score 0):

No. We cannot change or customize the attempt count/retry count. It is system controlled.

Customization is not possible, but biometry can be re-enabled. Once the user fails the biometric authentication consecutive number of attempts, [`biometryLockout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/laerror/code/2867589-biometrylockout) occurs. Once in lockout state, authentication can be triggered with the device passcode, and upon successful passcode attempt, biometric login will be available. It can be done with the method [`evaluatePolicy(_:localizedReason:reply:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514176-evaluatepolicy).
[`LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy/deviceownerauthentication) needs to be evaluated.

Sample code for unlocking biometric lockout:

```
    func unlockBiometricLockout(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
       context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication,
                              localizedReason: "Your device passcode is required to unlock Biometrics") { success, error in
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if success {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
         }
       }
    }
```